# VPN routing does not work

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, wireguard

I have a problem setting up wireguard.
My problem is packets from anywhere but the wireguard hos is not sent out on the wg0 interface.
I run wg0 with 192.168.96.1/24
ip forwarding is enabled. I can reach the webserver on wg0 host on both wg0 IP and its LAN IP.
But no traffic from other LAN hosts - Or answers to traffic masqueraded are getting sent out on wg0, but is is seen coming in on eth0.

```
ip route
192.168.96.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.96.1
```

I have lots of nat rules related to docker. But I have no idea why packets are not routed towards my wg0 host(s)

```
# iptables  --list-rules
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o hassio -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o hassio -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i hassio ! -o hassio -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i hassio -o hassio -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER -d 172.30.33.6/32 ! -i hassio -o hassio -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i hassio ! -o hassio -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o hassio -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

- 

```
# iptables -t nat --list-rules
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.32.0/23 ! -o hassio -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
...
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.33.6/32 -d 172.30.33.6/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i hassio -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:9000
....
-A DOCKER ! -i hassio -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.30.33.6:22
```

Comment: Found out that adding these 2 rules would allow the traffic to flow:    
`-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT`    
`-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`    
    
Guess some other rules would be cleaner/better ? I might want to run multiple VPNs here. Should I just drop the -P FORWARD DROP rule ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Docker installed, you definitely want to keep a FORWARD drop or reject policy.  I found it a bit cleaner to have Wireguard handle its own iptables rules using the `PostUp` and `PostDown` options in the config.  In your `wg0.conf` under the `[Interface]` section you should put something like (assuming hassio is your main network interface):

```
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i %i -o hassio -s 192.168.96.0/24 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.96.0/24 -o hassio -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -o hassio -s 192.168.96.0/24 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.96.0/24 -o hassio -j MASQUERADE
```

This then needs to be paired with a rule that allows the reverse FORWARD traffic: I personally opt for a more generic ESTABLISHED/RELATED rule in the form of `-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`.  I really don't know of any situation where I want to do anything other than allow already ESTABLISHED/RELATED sessions to continue.

P.S. - I also use "REJECT" policies for hosts that really are LAN only.  REJECT kicks out a ICMP packet when something isn't allowed whereas DROP just silently drops the connection; REJECT makes debugging quite a bit easier.